# The 10-year anniversary banner doesn't link anywhere by default; should it link to the blog post by default?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, sidebar

I noticed the sites celebrating their 10th anniversary have a banner in the sidebar, but currently only [Russian Language](https://rus.stackexchange.com) and [Movies&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) have the banner linking to their local meta post. For example, Spanish Language has an anniversary meta post [¡Cumplimos 10 años!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/cumplimos-10-a%c3%b1os), but the banner doesn't link to it.

Wouldn't it be better to have the banner link to [*The Overflow* 10-year article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/01/check-out-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old-in-q4/) by default until a dev links it to that site's meta thread?

[image: Screenshot of banner stating "Happy 10 year anniversary!"]

Comment: On Spanish Language, not linking to the local meta post was an intentional decision. Linking to the blog post could still be a good idea, though: we had not thought of that.